# Remove name from url query using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I remove the "**/page/2/**" from the url using a regular expression in javascript. Where the 2 can be any number ie. /page/**5**/. but "page" and the slashes will be consistently there.

**mydomain.com/posts/page/2/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern : `(.*)[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/$`

Full code :

```
var string = 'mydomain.com/posts/page/2/';
var result = /(.*)[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/$/.exec(string);
var wantedPath = result[1];
```

Testable here : http://jsfiddle.net/3h7dX/

note : *page* can be other thing as your number value.

Please, valid the answer to close your question if it is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this works great. I did however forget one step, need to first check that "page" shows up somewhere in the url if not then I will not run the regex. Do you have any ideas for handling that?

Comment: You can modify the regex to work only for page URL. And then make some check as you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/3h7dX/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
string = string.replace(/\/page\/\d+\//, "");
```

This should solve your problem. Example is under http://jsfiddle.net/AfR4D/